# Getting "Invalid parameter" exception on getReportsStats with no reason

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Can anyone help me with a fast code review?

```
$fields = array(
    'campaign_id',
    'spend'
);
$params = array(
    'data_columns' => $fields,
    'time_interval' => array(
        'day_start' => array(
            'year' => 2011,
            'month' => 9,
            'day' => 1
        ),
        'day_stop' => array(
            'year' => 2011,
            'month' => 9,
            'day' => 10
        ),
    ),
);
$stats = $adAccount->getReportsStats(array(), $params);
```

After running this code I am getting:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message 'Invalid parameter' in /home/maciekmp/public_html/face_test/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:129
fdfd
```

Comment: You are sending an empty `array()`.  Does `getReportsStats()` accept that?

Comment: Yes, there must be an array, because of function declaration. Btw. there is null in documentation but when I use it there is fatal error. I was trying to use non empty array also with no results.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? if so please post your answer

Comment: I did not test solution from @Rodnay but he can be right, instead I am using date_preset with 'yesterday'. I do not need more data for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following in the [facebook api developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/v2.2/).  Search on "async".  If the data you are querying is too old you will have to do an asynchronous call to the graph api.  Which is usually the case with the error you received.  The current version of the php-sdk does not support passing an async parameter out of the box.  Since AdAccount defaults to GET request and async calls to the graph api must be done with POST request, you will need to extend the  AdAccount class and create and prepare a request to use the POST method.

Comment: Thanks @Rodney for help, I will try that if we have little more time.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you try get more than 30 days of to the current date it shows this error.

29 days of data and it works, which is rather pointless! I'm going to ask in their developer forum.

```
$fields = array('campaign_id', 'total_actions', 'spend'); // The fields I   ask for?
$params = array(
    'data_columns' => array (
        'campaign_group_id',
        'total_actions',
        'social_impressions',
        'impressions',
        'unique_impressions',
        'clicks',

        'spend',
        'impressions',
       // 'action_values_28d_view'
    ),

    'time_interval'=>array(
       'time_start'=>mktime(0,0,0,1,17,2015),
        'time_stop'=>mktime(0,0,0,date("n"),date("d"),date("Y"))
    ),
        /*
    'time_ranges'=>array(
        array(
            'day_start'=>array(
                'day'=>1,
                'month'=>1,
                'year'=>2015,
            ),
            'day_stop'=>array(
                'day'=>13,
                'month'=>2,
                'year'=>2015,
                ),
            ),
        ),

    */
   // 'date_preset' => 'last_28_days',
    'time_increment'=>1,
);
```